# Getting information from one users collection when cycling through messages collection - Firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

My database is structured with a users collection and a messages collection (seen below). There will only be 1-2-1 messaging in the app (no chat rooms).The messages collection's documents are named as user1:user2.

I'm trying to create a page in my app where a user can see all the users they have chats with and then can click on each of those chats and open up the message chain with that user. I'm confident I know how to create the second part of this (the message chain) but I'm not sure how to pull back all of the current chats a user has.

So far I've got

```
    def load_chats(self):
        messages = self.my_firestore.db.collection(u'messages').stream()
        #self.users = self.my_firestore.db.collection(u'users').stream()
        for doc in messages:
            if self.local_id in doc.id: #This is checking if "user1" is in "user1:user2", for example
                chat_messages.add_widget(ChatButton) #Adds a new button each time it finds "user1" in the doc.id within messages
```

In this for loop, when I'm creating the button for the chats I need information from the `users` collection so I can display the name of the person the chat is with.

However, I'm not sure how to do this  - beyond putting a for loop within `for doc in messages` which cycles through `self.users` and returns the user information if it matches "user2". This would create a huge number of reads so I'm not even entertaining my crazy idea!

[image: messages collection]

[image: messages collection continued]

[image: users collection]

Any help would be much appreciated, let me know if it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `Participants` array field to your chat groups:

```
data = {
    'GroupId': 'userOneID:userTwoID',
    'Participants': ['userOneID', 'userTwoID']
}
```

Then you could query for chat groups where a user is either `userOne` or `userTwo` in a chat group:

```
chatGroups = self.my_firestore.db.collection(u'messages') \
                 .where('Participants', 'array_contains', 'userID') \
                 .stream()
```

Comment: Thanks, would this use fewer reads than this solution: ````def user_messages(self):
        messages = self.my_firestore.db.collection(u'messages').stream()
        user_messages = self.root.get_screen("user_messages").ids['user_messages_layout']
        for doc in messages:
            if self.local_id in doc.id:
                user_id = doc.id.split(":")[1]
                user = self.my_firestore.db.collection(u'users').document(user_id).get()```` I created it this way initially but if your suggestion will use fewer reads (or generally be more efficient) I'll change to what you said

Comment: Apologies the formatting has come out poorly, I'm not sure how to add code properly in a comment

Comment: Yes, the `where` filter avoids loading the entire `messages` collection each time.